# An app.yaml (or appengine-web.xml) file is required to deploy this directory as an App Engine application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml, app.yaml

This is the first time I am deploying something on cloud, and I followed article.

I have created application, and want to deploy it on Google Cloud. While doing it I am getting error for app.yaml file.

[image]

[image]

My app.yaml is,

[image]

When I execute "ls" command, it display only 1 file,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the command `gcloud app deploy` is unable to find your application `app.yaml` file.

If you do not provide any argument to `gcloud app deploy` it will look for an `app.yaml` file in the current directory.

It seems for your screenshot that you are in the Cloud Shell home directory, one directory above the one that contains your code and the actual `app.yaml` file, the one named `xxxx-point-gcp`.

Please, either change the working directory to `xxxx-point-gcp` and then run `gcloud app deploy`, or run `gcloud app deploy` passing as argument the full path to the `app.yaml` file:

```
gcloud app deploy ~/xxxx-point-gcp/app.yaml
```

Please, substitute the `xxxx` placeholders for the appropriate paths.

Please, see the [relevant documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `gcloud app deploy` from the folder which contains `app.yaml` file.